# Docusign api - can a completed envelope tell me which doc in the envelope had no signing tabs?

Tags: docusignapi

Using the Docusign REST api, I can get a list of the documents inside a completed envelope. Is there any api call that would tell me, for instance, that document 2 in the list has no signing tabs? For our application, we need to know which documents in the envelope were signed ( had signing tabs ) and which ones did not need a signature.

Comment: Related question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249190/getting-all-tabs-from-a-template-using-rest-docusign-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[GetEnvelopeRecipeints](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/)** API and retrieve all the tabs in an envelope by passing the **include_tabs=true** query string parameter.

The response will contain tabs on all documents in the envelope. You can then filter the tab list based on the document Id

```
  GET restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=true&include_extended=true
```

Comment: Yep. Worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help.